# Trimming unwanted characters

Tags: r

I have a very large data set (CSV) with information about bicycle counts from a bike share system. The information I'm working with is the time at which bicycles were taken out of the racks (departure time) and also the total travel time. What I want to do is to add them so I can get the arrival time at the arrival station. The departure time variable is FECHA_HORA_RETIRO and the travel time variable is TIEMPO_USO. The former, which is read by R as factor object, is in the following format: "23/01/2017 19:55:16". On the other hand, TIEMPO_USO is read by R as a character and it's in the following format: "0:17:46".

```
> head(viajes_ecobici_2017$FECHA_HORA_RETIRO)
[1] 28/01/2017 13:51 17/01/2017 16:24 12/01/2017 16:38 25/01/2017 10:31

> head(viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO)
[1] "1:35:37" "0:11:17" "0:32:51" "0:31:29" "1:31:59" "0:21:43" "0:5:43"
```

I first used strptime to get everything in the desired format

```
 > viajes_ecobici_2017$FECHA_HORA_RETIRO    =format(strptime(viajes_ecobici_2017$FECHA_HORA_RETIRO,format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

> viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO = format(strptime(viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO, format="%H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M:%S")
```

This works with most observations. However, several observations became NA values after running this code. I went back to the original data to see why this was happening and created a variable with just the observations that became NA. When I looked closer at this observations I saw they have this format "\t\t01/06/2017 00:01". How can I get rid of the "\t\t" while preserving the rest of the information?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Give examples of specific dates that file.

Comment: Maybe change your title, since you're really asking about trimming unwanted characters?

Comment: Changed! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trimws()` trims white space (including tab characters, `\t`) from the ends of a character variable:

```
 viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO <- trimws(viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO)
```

For what it's worth, `readr::read_csv()` has a built-in `trimws` option (which is `TRUE` by default).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the variable with the problem is TIEMPO_USO, then a simple regex would take care of the tab characters ("\t")

```
viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO <- gsub("^\\t\\t","", viajes_ecobici_2017$TIEMPO_USO)
```